# When to delete project obj and bin folders?

Tags: visual-studio

Usually I do it when I am about to publish an application with a lot of code changes applied to.  The problem is that I do it to feel good not because I am certain that the process really needs it.

I am not asking about cleaning the folders but deleting them. What valid reasons are there to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a big difference between deleting bin folders and total clearing them. In any way, the entire folder content is removed and new content is copied. ASP.NET Server is automatically restarted (if you didn't shut down it first) when the bin folder content is changed. 
I personally usually delete the folder content but do not delete the folder itself. But as I said, there is no big difference at all.

Comment: What if you do not clean or delete before publishing?

Comment: Then the folder will contain old assemblies. If you won't replace them (for a reason), your application will use new and old assemblies. This is not a problem if old assembly code was not changed. Then new assemblies will use it old assemblies correctly. However, if not all updated assemblies were replaced on the target server, you can get an exception or even unexpected behavior (the worst situation) that you won't reproduce on staging or a local server.  This is a very rare case, but I prefer to avoid it.